# Unknown column in field list

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I am getting the following error about an unknown column 'review_id' in field list. To recreate it, from the django shell I can run,

```
from reviews.models import Review
r = Review.objects.get(pk=1)
r.delete()
```

Here is the review model:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey('projects.Person', related_name='reviewer', null=True)
    reviewee = models.ForeignKey('projects.Person', related_name='reviewee', null=True)
    review_type = models.ForeignKey(ReviewType, null=True)
    review_status = models.ForeignKey(ReviewStatus, null=True)
    cycle = models.ForeignKey(ReviewCycle, null=True)
    # Date time of original instance creation; not to be edited
    orig_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    # Date review submitted
    submitted_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    # Store historical revisions
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

This is on a live site, so I can't reset the database. When I look at the reviews_review table in mysql, there is no column review_id (there is a column 'id'). I have tried rerunning migrations and running syncdb.

There is one model built on top of Review called peerEvaluation. Presumably Django tries to delete the peerEvaluation as well as the Review instance when you try to delete the Review instance. The code for peerEvaluation is:

```
class peerEvaluation(models.Model):
    review = models.ForeignKey(Review, null=True)
    # Text fields
    projects_worked_on = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    analytical_well = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    analytical_improve = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    communication_well = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    communication_improve = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    planning_well = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    planning_improve = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    teamwork_well = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    teamwork_improve = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    # Date time of original instance creation, not to be edited
    orig_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    # Store historical revisions
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

Any help would be super appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Have you generated your migrations for the `PeerEvaluation` model?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the historical tables (from simple_history). The migrations weren't applying with them. I deleted those tables, re-ran migrations, and it worked. Not sure how to make it work without deleting the historical tables, but fortunately they weren't crucial in this case.